# How to prove $v(x,t) = x\cdot Du(x,t)+2tu_t(x,t)$ is also a solution of the heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

How to prove that
$$
    v(x,t) = x \cdot Du(x,t)+2tu_t(x,t)$ 
$$
is also a solution of  the heat equation. $u_t(x,t)-\Delta u(x,t)=0$

Where $ u:R^{d \times1}\rightarrow R$ and  $"\cdot" $ is dot product. $x\in R^d$ and  $t\in R$

I have checked other answers where they used the fact that $u^\lambda = u(\lambda x, \lambda ^2 t)$ satisfy heat equation and that $v=\left.\frac{du^\lambda}{d\lambda}\right|_{\lambda=1}=v(x,t)$, I can see both facts are true. But I do not see how to use them to prove that $v$ satisfies the equation.

all kinds of solutions are highly appreciated.

Comment: If a function satisfies the heat equation, do its derivatives also?

Comment: @NinadMunshi That the same doubt that I have!!! Do you know maybe any reference that mentions that result?

Comment: There is no reference, more or less an obvious result. Start with with heat equation then differentiate both sides w.r.t. an arbitrary partial. Then swap the order of the partials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$(\partial_t - \Delta )u = 0 \implies \partial^\alpha (\partial_t - \Delta ) u = (\partial_t - \Delta )( \partial^\alpha u) = 0$$